# What do ListActivity and ListView provide beyond a regular Activity and View?

Tags: android

In Android, what functionality do ListActivity and ListView provide beyond a regular Activity and View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ListActivity` provides some convenience methods for using a `ListView` inside of the `Activity`. The best example would be that it is very easy to attach a data source (`ArrayList` or `Cursor` to a Database) to the `ListView` and have it be displayed to the user. The `ListView` can also be made clickable.

Answer (score 0):

[ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) hosts a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) object that can be bound to different data sources.

In short:

If your `Activity` will have a `ListView` check `ListActivity`. It might help you a little.